# Blending edges of materials together?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, texture-painting, procedural

Id like to blend these materials together so there's not such a straight edge. I know you can mix shaders with nodes but I dont know how to localize it to a specific edge. Right now I just have them in separate material slots assigned to the different parts of the mesh.

[image]

Comment: you could use one material only and paint a b&w picture that you would use as a mask between the 2 parts

Comment: To extend moonboots' comment in regards to your statement "I don't know how to localize..." - you could change the materials to white and black and bake that to an image and then perhaps blur that image or otherwise do something with that information that would now control the transition between the two parts of your new material...

Answer (score 3):

If the limit between the 2 colors is blurry I think you have no other choice but to create one unique material and use a black or white image texture as a mask factor in a *Mix Shader* (or use *Vertex Paint* if your topology is dense enough). Then you can paint your object with white or black:

[image]

[image]

For something as simple as a vertical gradient you could also use the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate* and the *Z* output of a *Separate XYZ*:

[image]

[image]